# difference between reading proc files via shell (cat) or via program (fread)

Tags: c, linux, callback, proc

I have a `kernel module` creating an entry in `proc-fs` and a `userspace-program` that reads the file.
My `proc read-function` looks like:

```
typedef struct {
  int integer;
  unsigned long ulong;
  char string[100];
  float floatt;
  bool booll;
  u16 crc;
} struktur;

static int round = 0, len = 0, temp = 0, err;
struktur *pde_data_p;

int proc_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp) {
  int i;
  unsigned char *crcbuf;
  struktur struct_buf;

  pde_data_p = PDE_DATA(file_inode(filp));
  crcbuf = (unsigned char*)pde_data_p;
  memcpy(&struct_buf, pde_data_p, sizeof(struktur));
  if (pde_data_p == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "pde->data == NULL\n");
    round = 0;
    return 0;
  }

  if (round == 0)
    temp = sizeof(struktur);

  if (count > temp)
    count = temp;

  struct_buf.crc = crc16(struct_buf.crc, crcbuf, sizeof(struktur)-sizeof(unsigned short));

  err = copy_to_user(buf, pde_data_p, count);

  //if (err == 0) {    // copy_to_user finished
    round = 0;
    temp = 0;        // taking this line out makes it work in the prog but not with my cat
    return temp;
  //} else {           // copy_to_user failed -> return number of bytes that have not been copied
    //temp = err;
    //round++;
    //return temp;
  //}
}
```

My `program code` is:

```
typedef struct {
  int integer;
  unsigned long ulong;
  char string[100];
  float floatt;
  bool booll;
  unsigned short crc;
} struktur;

int main(void) {
  int i;
  struktur str_inp;
  unsigned short crc = 0;
  unsigned char *str_p = (unsigned char*)&str_inp;


  FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/sen/entry", "r");
  fread(&str_inp, 1, sizeof(struktur), fp);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

As you can see my proc read-function returns the number of bytes read, not zero.
This way my program works fine but when I try to read via cat (cat /proc/sen/entry) it never finishes because it never returns 0.
When I change my code and `return 0` after `copy_to_user` has finished, reading via `cat` works fine but my program seems reads random memory. When I return half of the number of copied bytes, just half of the data read by the user-space program is correct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67015/discussion-on-question-by-hossi-difference-between-reading-proc-files-via-shell).

Answer (score 0):

What has to be returned by your `proc_read` function depends on the position which is handed over in `*offp`. If it is only required to work for your given userspace program code and for `cat` (not for partial reads of `struktur`) it suffices to

```
    if (*offp) return 0;            // no more data to return
    else *offp = sizeof (struktur); // file position after data returned
```

- this statement goes before the `copy_to_user()`.